# Values not setting up correctly in function scope for if/else if

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am trying to review some jquery.  I wrote a simple function that should count the time that I am hovering over a element.

My intention is to subtract the time I left the function from the time I entered the function.

However, my value for mouse enter which is set in the if statement returns to zero in the else if block.  I set the value at the top of the function to have an initial value of 0.  The value changes when it runs through the if statement, but once it hits the else if portion of my function the value returns to it's initial value.

Here is my function below

```
$('.navbar').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(evt) {
        var mouseenterTime = 0;
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var mouseoverTime;
        if(evt.type === 'mouseenter') {
            mouseenterTime = currentTime.getTime();
        }
        else if (evt.type === 'mouseleave') {
            mouseoverTime =currentTime.getTime(); 
            console.log('enter in else if',mouseenterTime); //0
            console.log('leave', mouseoverTime);
            var time = mouseoverTime - mouseenterTime;
        }
    console.log('mouseenterTime',mouseenterTime); //initial time then 0

    })
```

Any direction or corrections would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your first line is setting mouseenterTime to be zero, so if a mouseleave event happens, the if clause doesn't happen and the time will be reset. You just need to store that variable that you're resetting outside of the binding so it doesn't get reset.

Comment: I am seeing that from the other comments thank you.

Comment: Arun is correct below. I've updated your code to reflect this change, if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/dhkd8u90/

Comment: @CoryW. appreciate you taking the time.  I spent an hour fixing looking at that error.  These are the simple things of javascript I need to study more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring local variables, which will be created everytime the callback is called, ie on mouseenter and mouseleave so every time you will have reference to a new variable not to the previous variable.

You can use a shared variable to solve this problem like

```js
var enteredTime = 0;
$('.navbar').hover(function(evt) {
  enteredTime = new Date();
}, function() {
  var ctime = new Date();
  var time = ctime.getTime() - enteredTime.getTime();
  snippet.log('time spend ' + time + 'ms')
})
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">navbar</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's defined locally on each call, if the `else if` part is ran, that means the `if` part was not, hence why it's called `else if`. So the value is never changed if the first if-statement isn't ran.

```
var mouseenterTime = 0; // defined
var currentTime = new Date();
var mouseoverTime;
if(evt.type === 'mouseenter') {
    // This part is not ran, so it doesn't matter
}
else if (evt.type === 'mouseleave') {
    // mouseenterTime wasn't changed so it's still 0
}
```

A basic solution would be to make `mouseenterTime` more global, basically placing `var mouseenterTime = 0;` outside the function.

Comment: Others have pointed this out as well.  I see my error.  Thank you for the commented lines.